# list style not applying to the menu

Tags: html, css

Hello I made clickable dropdown and I want to put circles behind the text on UL LI but it doesnt applying, I search in my css code I am not removing the circle anywhere. Can someone see if I am doing something wrong :/

HTML CODE:

```
    <ul id = "mobddown" style="display: none;">
        <a href="#"><li>Берово</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Берово</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Берово</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Берово</li></a>
    </ul>
```

CSS CODE:

```
#mobddown{
    font-size: 2em;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: circle;
}

#mobddown li{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em;
    width: 100%;
}

#mobddown a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
}

#mobddown li:hover{
    background-color: #35aa96;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: you need to add `ul` to the id's in the css

Comment: I did that now the margin is making it awful and the circle is still not there.https://jsfiddle.net/5wq7ja4u/

Comment: see the answer below, I should have spotted that also. Your markup is invalid.

Comment: I Saw it you can check my answer can some of you guys did it in the jsfiddle and send it to me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things in your code .

1. Firstly li should be immediate child of ul
2. Remove padding and margin on ul  but let it be on li
3. Li is already block element which would have 100% of width

check this snippet

```css
#mobddown {
  font-size: 2em;
}
#mobddown li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.4em;
  list-style-type: circle;
}
#mobddown a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
#mobddown li a:hover {
  background-color: #35aa96;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul id="mobddown">
  <li> <a href="#">Берово</a>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#">Берово</a>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#">Берово</a>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#">Берово</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It soemhow helped but I want when i hover on it the color to go all the way from the left to right and the circle not to dissapear :v

Comment: nope.. it doesnt work. but you helped me with the margin i can try different ways now to do it :)

Answer (score 2):

The `li` tag should be the immediate child of the `ul` tag. Put the link inside the list-item like so:

```
<ul id = "mobddown" style="display: none;">
    <li><a href="#">Берово</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

If you want the entire `<a>` tag to be clickable, you can also add the bullet point by using CSS:

```
.bulletPoint:before{
    content:"• "
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<div id = "mobddown" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#" class="bulletPoint">Берово</a>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: It was like that before. But I changed it because my li width is 100% and I was able to click the text only. I tried adding width: 100% on the "a" and it was not working. EDIT: Its still not working even like that

Comment: the `ul` also needs to be added to their css rules.

Comment: Then all rules for li a dissapears.. SOmehow :/

Comment: @Fred-ii- no it doesn't. `#mobddown` in the css will select the element with id="mobddown". you don't need to make it any more specific.

Comment: @Punit on many occasions it was needed. Least, in stuff I built. OP needs to learn how to use their developer tools. I'd test this, but I'm not really able to right now.

Comment: EDIT: guys i tried removing the css code for those items and suddenly the circles apeared i am doing something wrong in the css i cant tell what it is.

Comment: Check out my edit, there is another solution that might help you.